# Joomla Component: View: Get values from field

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I'm new to Joomla, especially to component development. Anyway, here's my question:

**site\views\plaingallery\tmpl\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_PLAINGALLERY_PLAINGALLERY_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[COM_PLAINGALLERY_PLAINGALLERY_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
    <fields name="request"
        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_plaingallery/models/fields">
        <fieldset name="request">
            <field name="galleryFolder" type="folderlist" default="" recursive="true"
                label="Select a folder" directory="images" filter="" exclude="" width="300"
                hide_none="true" hide_default="true" stripext="" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</metadata>
```

**site\views\plaingallery\view.html.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * HTML View class for the PlainGallery Component
 */
class PlainGalleryViewPlainGallery extends JViewLegacy
{
    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Assign data to the view      
        $this->msg = 'I am new to Joomla';

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I access the value from the field[name="galleryFolder"] the user provided in the menu configuration?

Thanks for your help! I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I just use $params->get('galleryFolder')

Comment: This question seems more appropriately posted at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.   You may wish to custom flag this page for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter is located in the query variable of the menu item.

You can try this for example:

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    /* Default Page fallback*/
    $active = $app->getMenu()->getActive();
    if (NULL == $active) {
        $active = $app->getMenu()->getDefault();
    }

    if ( isset($active->query['galleryFolder']) ) {
        $galleryFolder = $active->query['galleryFolder'];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working unfortunately. `$this->params` returns


object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)#261 (3) {
  ["data":protected]=>
  object(stdClass)#259 (9) {
    ["show_page_heading"]=>
    NULL
    ["menu_image"]=>
    string(18) "images/galerie.jpg"
    ["menu_text"]=>
    int(1)
    ["menu_show"]=>
    int(1)
    ["secure"]=>
    int(0)
    ["page_title"]=>
    string(7) "Galerie"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["page_rights"]=>
    NULL
    ["robots"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["initialized":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["separator"]=>
  string(1) "."
}

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here... what could that be?

Comment: @Erando I adjusted my answer

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! `query['catid']` is not set though but `query['galleryFolder']` exists so that's working after all. Danke!